# ¿Cómo puedo poner resaltado de sintaxis o bloques de código en WordPress.com?

Tags: vb.net, wordpress, sintaxis

Tengo un blog en Wordpress.com que se trata principalmente de programación, por tanto tengo que dar más de algún ejemplo de código.

Hasta ahora lo que hacía era ponerlo pre-formateado y ponerle los colores manualmente, pero a la larga esto se vuelve tedioso...

Cabe destacar que mi plan de WordPress.com es el gratuito, por lo que no puedo instalar plugins.

Ya intenté con la etiqueta [sourcecode lang="vb"] y [code language="vb"], pero no me dan el efecto que esperaba, si bien cumple con su función, pero... la fuente no me convence del todo...

Así que me gustaría saber si hay alguna página que se pueda implementar en WordPress.com, algo así como un embed.

Así es como se mira con la etiqueta [code language="vb"]

[image: Así es como se mira con la etiqueta [code language="vb"]

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Kevin, bienvenido a Stackoverflow. ¿Qué quieres decir con que no te da el efecto que esperabas, que no funciona o que no se ve con los colores que tú esperabas? ¿Lo has puesto usando el modo de edición `HTML`, en vez del modo visual? El modo correcto sería: **`[code language="vb"]
aquí tu código
[/code]`**. Activa la pestaña `HTML` para hacerlo, no la pantalla `Visual`.

Comment: Lo hice en la pestaña de HTML, pero el problema es que la fuente se mira demasiado grande y los colores no coinciden con los originarios de vb.net, me gustaría saber si hubiera alguna web con embed o algo así que me permita poner el bloque de código.

Comment: He añadido una imagen de cómo se mira con esa etiqueta.

Comment: Me temo que será casi imposible lograr lo que pretendes desde un sitio de Wordpress.com ... a lo sumo podrías (quizá), con mucha dificultad, aplicar reglas de estilo CSS que vayan dando el color que tú quieras a los diferentes elementos. Esto no estoy del todo seguro que puedas hacerlo, y segundo, aunque logres hacerlo funcionar, supondrá que tendrías que aplicar estilos en el mismo código. Sería aun trabajo verdaderamente tremendo. Sinceramente, yo me decidiría por un dominio y un hosting sencillo, aunque haya que pagar, no es tan costoso y notarás la diferencia.

Comment: Creo que me puedo acostumbrar a esa etiqueta, siempre gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar los gist de github, te ofrecen un resaltado de sintaxis diferente y funciona en wordpress.com a la perfección. Simplemente:

1. Crea un gist.
2. Una vez creado copias la URL del mismo y la pegas en la pestaña visual.

Automáticamente wordpress lo detecta y te muestra el código con el resaltado de gist.
Para mas información te dejo la página que explica con mas detalle: https://en.support.wordpress.com/gist/

Espero haberte ayudado.